# Is it possible to check is Parse user is logged in from the server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am logging in/signing up users client side but I would like to check if their logged in from the server upon a page landing get request.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible and it is what you are supposed to do. Never trust client-side.

Comment: @Cray how should I check with Parse server?

Answer (score 0):

You should have something server side which checks if a user is authenticated, this is the secure way as you can't trust verification client side as client side code can be altered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Cloud Code function to check if the user is logged In.
Some simple example:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('isLoggedIn', async (req) => {
  const { user } = req;

  if (!user) {
    return { isLogged: false };
  }

  const sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();

  try {
    const result = await Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: `${Parse.serverURL}/sessions/me`,
      headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": Parse.applicationId,
        "X-Parse-JavaScript-API-Key": Parse.javaScriptKey,
        "X-Parse-Session-Token": sessionToken,
      }
    });

    return { isLogged: true }
  } catch (e) {
    return { isLogged: false }
  }
});
```

Then you can use this cloud code function like this:

```
const isLoggedInFunc = async () => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = await Parse.Cloud.run("isLoggedIn");

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    // if logged in do what you want
  } else {
    // if not logged in do what you want
    // for example redirect user to login page or something ...
  }
}
```

Hope this will help :)